# Prove that following graph problem is in $L$

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, turing-machines

I have some interesting problem:

> Prove that following problem is in $L$ (decidable in logarythmic
>   time).   *Decide if given undirected graph $G=(\{1,\ldots,n\}, E)$ such
>   that $\forall_{i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}} i\le j \to \operatorname{dist}(1, i) \le \operatorname{dist}(1,j)$.*
>   Graph is represented as adjacent matrix.

This is exercise that I can't deal with it. I know USTCON problem and I suppose that it may be useful (crucial) here. However, I can't solve it. Can anyone try to  help me defeat it ?

Comment: The notation $\mathsf{L}$ usually refers to logarithmic *space* rather than time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N_k$ be the set of vertices at distance $k$ from 1. A graph satisfies the property if the sets $N_k$ are intervals, and $N_{k-1} < N_k$ (every member of $N_{k-1}$ is smaller than every member of $N_k$). We will check this property inductively: assuming $N_{k-1}$ is known (starting with $N_0 = \{1\}$), we will show how to calculate $N_k$ and verify that it has the correct properties.

Suppose that $N_{k-1} = \{a,\ldots,b\}$. If $b = n$, we can stop. Otherwise, go over all neighbors of the vertices in $N_{k-1}$, and record the minimal and maximal indices $c,d$ encountered among those larger than $b$. Verify that $c = b+1$. Now go over all $e \in \{c,\ldots,d\}$, and verify that it is a neighbor of some vertex in $N_{k-1}$. If so, we have verified that $N_k = \{c,\ldots,d\}$, and can continue with $N_{k+1}$.

You can check that this algorithm can be implemented in logspace.

Comment: "You can check that this algorithm can be implemented in logspace."  Task was about log time, no logspace

Comment: The problem cannot be decided in logarithmic time (you can show this using an adversary argument). The notation L, which appears in the question, refers to logarithmic *space*.

Comment: Oh no, on the my exam I thought that I must show log time - I know adversary technique :D So this task became fairly easy as I think. I will analyze and I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it was enlightening. Adversary argument is very easy. Using log time we can't see every node..